# total sales per year distributed in a monthly tiered approach

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

i have been breaking my mind trying to solve this too big of a problem for my excel skills and now i call for your help.

[image: Tiered approach Spreadsheet]

My problem is that given a sales number like for example 150Million. I need this sum to be distributed monthly 4 tiered lines. See attached image.

- Tier 1 = distribute monthly amount until total amount in tier 1 line is 120Million
- Tier 2 = distribute monthly amount into next months until tier 2 amount is 7.2Million
- Tier 3 = distribute monthly amount into next months until tier 3 total is 7.2Million
- Tier 4 = remaining amount exceeding

Should Sales be lower 150Million, then the tiered lines should calculate accordingly.

your help is really much appreciated.

Comment: So the input is row `7` and the output is `13:16`?

Comment: Hi Scott, Input would be in A2. It then gets distributed in percent monthly in lines C7:N7. Then the tiering process is calculated in Line 13:16 based on the monthly numbers in Line7

Comment: What is your question? How to calculate route 13:16 or row 7? Or both?

Comment: Hi Máté, only how to calculate lines 13:16. Line 7 is solved  with (A2/c$5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are formulas you can use for your calculation in columns C-N:

- row 13: `=MIN(2*$B13-SUM($B13:B13),C$7)`
- row 14-15: `=MIN(2*$B14-SUM($B14:B14),C$7-SUM(C$13:C13))`
- row 16: `=C7-SUM(C13:C15)`

[image]

Comment: Hi Máté, first of all thank you very much for your reply and solution. After converting the formulas into german language it works except that it wont make the break in K13.  Any idea why it behaves like this? Currently trying to figure it out myself, reading about the MIN formula.

Comment: hold on, i think i figured it out.

Comment: Dear Máté, your solution works like a charm :-). Thank you so very much for taking the time and helping me out. I learned many new excel formulas the last days while searching for a solution. Cheers!